# Is there a way to remove indents for question parts>

Tags: indentation, exam

[image]

For the example above, how can I remove the indent from the parts so (a), (b), (c), (d) all line up with "Question 1"?

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\linespread{1.6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.25in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{} 
\chead{} 
\rhead{} 
\lfoot{} 
\cfoot{\footnotesize{Page \thepage \ of \pageref{finalpage} -- \titlehd \ (\examcode)}} 
\rfoot{} 

\newcommand{\institution}{Maths Extension 2}
\newcommand{\titlehd}{Complex Numbers}
\newcommand{\examtype}{Summer Holidays Examination}
\newcommand{\examdate}{2021-2022}
\newcommand{\readtime}{10 Minutes}
\newcommand{\writetime}{THREE Hours}
\newcommand{\materials}{Non-programmable Calculators}

\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{1.5cm}
\newpage
\begin{questions}
\marksnotpoints
\pointsinrightmargin
\pointformat{\bfseries\themarginpoints}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion} \hspace{2mm}\textbf{(\totalpoints \hspace{1mm}\points)}\hfill}


\question
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{parts}


\part[1]\text{If $(x+iy)^{2n}=a+ib$ where} $x,y,a,b,n$ $\in{\Bbb{Z}}$ find the value of $(y-ix)^{4n}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ 
 
\vspace{8mm}
\part[2] Let $w=\cos{\frac{2\pi}{7}}+i\sin{\frac{2\pi}{7}}$. Show that $w, w^4$ and $w^5$ form the sides of an equilateral triangle. 

\vspace{8mm}
\part
\begin{subparts}
\subpart[2] Find the solutions to the equation $z^n-1=0$ where $n$ is odd.

\vspace{2mm}
\subpart[2]Hence show that $\cos{\frac{2\pi}{n}}+\cos{\frac{4\pi}{n}}+...+\cos{\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}}$ is independent of $n$.
\end{subparts}
\vspace{0.8cm}


\part[3]Let $w=\frac{2}{1+z}$. If $|z|=1$ and $0<\arg{z}<\frac{2\pi}{3}$, sketch the complex number $w$ 
\vspace{1cm}
\end{parts}
\newpage
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add a minimal example of your code?

Comment: @campa I've added the code in the preamble and for the example itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the newcommand `\questionx` instead of `\question`

```
\newcommand{\questionx}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \marksnotpoints
    \qformat{\textbf{Question~\thequestion} \hspace{1ex}\textbf{(\totalpoints \enspace \points)}\hfill}
    \pointsinrightmargin%
    \pointformat{\textbf{\themarginpoints}}% 
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{(m)\hskip\labelsep}%
    \question\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}
}
```

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\linespread{1.6}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.25in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}

\usepackage{showframe} % show margins

\newcommand{\questionx}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \marksnotpoints
    \qformat{\textbf{Question~\thequestion} \hspace{1ex}\textbf{(\totalpoints \enspace \points)}\hfill}
    \pointsinrightmargin%
    \pointformat{\textbf{\themarginpoints}}% 
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{(m)\hskip\labelsep}%
    \question\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}
} 

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\institution}{Maths Extension 2}
\newcommand{\titlehd}{Complex Numbers}
\newcommand{\examtype}{Summer Holidays Examination}
\newcommand{\examdate}{2021-2022}
\newcommand{\readtime}{10 Minutes}
\newcommand{\writetime}{THREE Hours}
\newcommand{\materials}{Non-programmable Calculators}

\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{1.5cm}
\newpage
\begin{questions}
%   \marksnotpoints
%   \pointsinrightmargin
%   \pointformat{\bfseries\themarginpoints}
%   \qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion} \hspace{2mm}\textbf{(\totalpoints \hspace{1mm}\points)}\hfill}
        
    \questionx{%
    \vspace*{3mm}
    \begin{parts}       
        
        \part[1]\text{If $(x+iy)^{2n}=a+ib$ where} $x,y,a,b,n$ $\in{\Bbb{Z}}$ find the value of $(y-ix)^{4n}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ 
        
        \vspace{8mm}
        \part[2] Let $w=\cos{\frac{2\pi}{7}}+i\sin{\frac{2\pi}{7}}$. Show that $w, w^4$ and $w^5$ form the sides of an equilateral triangle. 
        
        \vspace{8mm}
        \part
        \begin{subparts}
            \subpart[2] Find the solutions to the equation $z^n-1=0$ where $n$ is odd.
            
            \vspace{2mm}
            \subpart[2]Hence show that $\cos{\frac{2\pi}{n}}+\cos{\frac{4\pi}{n}}+...+\cos{\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}}$ is independent of $n$.
        \end{subparts}
        \vspace{0.8cm}
        
        
        \part[3]Let $w=\frac{2}{1+z}$. If $|z|=1$ and $0<\arg{z}<\frac{2\pi}{3}$, sketch the complex number $w$ 
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{parts}
}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** (after follow up)

To allow page break within parts use

```
\newcommand{\questionx}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \marksnotpoints
    \qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion} \hspace{2mm}\textbf{(\totalpoints \hspace{1mm}\points)}\hfill}
    \pointsinrightmargin%
    \pointformat{\textbf{\themarginpoints}}% 
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{(m)\hskip\labelsep}%
    \question\hspace*{-\leftmargin}#1% changed <<<<<<<<<<
} 

\renewcommand{\partshook}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
}
```

[image: f]

Comment: Very good :-) :-)

Comment: @SimonDispa When I do it on one of the questions with a figure (diagram) in it, it has trouble rendering the diagram and has an error message that says "not in outer par mode, undefined control sequence, missing number treated as zero". Can you help just the code a little so it works for figures as well?

Comment: @SimonDispa For some reason, it seems to not obey the newpage command in the middle of a question and automatically starts a new page if the question doesn't fit over one page but then it crams everything onto that newpage

Comment: @SimonDispa Ok I figured ou the diagram problem, can you help with the questionx command cramming eveything onto one page?

Comment: @Quippy Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "partshook" to get at lengths associated with parts.  Note that I created something more like a minimum compile-able file, as your file gave me trouble.  I didn't bother making the equations correct.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}   
\vspace{2mm}

% ***********
\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}
% **********

\question
\begin{parts}
    
    \part[1] If $(x+iy)^{2n}=a+ib$ where $x,y,a,b,n$ $\in{{Z}}$ find the value of $(y-ix)^{4n}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ 
    
    \vspace{8mm}
    \part[2] Let $w=\cos{\frac{2\pi}{7}}+i\sin{\frac{2\pi}{7}}$. Show that $w, w^4$ and $w^5$ form the sides of an equilateral triangle. 
    
    \vspace{8mm}
    \part
    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart[2] Find the solutions to the equation $z^n-1=0$ where $n$ is odd.
        
        \vspace{2mm}
        \subpart[2]Hence show that $\cos{\frac{2\pi}{n}}+\cos{\frac{4\pi}{n}}+...+\cos{\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}}$ is independent of $n$.
    \end{subparts}
    \vspace{0.8cm}
    
    
    \part[3]Let $w=\frac{2}{1+z}$. If $|z|=1$ and $0<\arg{z}<\frac{2\pi}{3}$, sketch the complex number $w$ 
    \vspace{1cm}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

This yields
[image].  Of course, the parts letter now overlaps with the question number -- but that's an issue inherent with your request.